# How does Xcode know my commit history?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

When I started my project I used Git in the terminal to track changes. Then I realized source control is built into Xcode. So I committed all my changes, everything worked well. Then I went to history in Xcode and saw all my previous commits made from the terminal.

**How does Xcode know about those commits?** Especially since I haven't signed into my Git repo in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git history is kept locally in the project's `.git` folder. When you open Xcode, it finds your local `.git` folder and uses it to show the project's history.

You don't have to push to your remote Git repo for that, since the history is kept locally.

Comment: Thanks! If I was on a different machine and wanted to see my commits, like `git log`, how would I do that? Because I haven't signed into my repo with Xcode.

Comment: The easiest way to synchronize both machines would be a through a remote Git repo. Add the remote to your first machine (`git remote add origin https://....`), then push (`git push origin master`), then clone the project on the second machine (`git clone https://....`)